# chaining curry functions with lodash

Tags: javascript, chaining, currying, lodash

Inspired by [this article on curry functions](http://hughfdjackson.com/javascript/why-curry-helps/) I was trying to chain them and came up with this solution. I'm not sure about the mixin though since I somehow feel that lodash might have such a function allready. If so, what is this function called?

```
var _ = require('lodash');

var get = _.curry(function(property, object) {return object[property]});

var map = _.curry(function(fn, objects){ return objects.map(fn) });

var json = {
    "user": "hughfdjackson",
    "posts": [
        { "title": "why curry?", "contents": "..." },
        { "title": "prototypes: the short(est possible) story", "contents": "..." }
    ]
}

_.mixin({
    then:function(input, fn) {return fn(input);}
});

_(json)
    .then(get('posts'))
    .then(map(get('title')))
    .tap(console.log)
```

Comment: No, there is no such function in lodash. Lodash does not think of itself as a wrapper that could be mapped over, but as the plain values.

Comment: @Bergi: `_([1, 2, 3); //=> {__chain__: false, __wrapped__: [1, 2, 3]}`.  So if `console.log` were replaced with `console.log.bind(console)` this would just work, logging the post titles and returning a LoDash wrapper.

Comment: @ScottSauyet: Yes, it would work. I'm saying that there is no "native" alternative to `then`

Comment: @Bergi, yes of course.  Sorry.  It does seem that LoDash does in some ways think of itself as a wrapper function.  I'm not sure I really understand the rationale.  But then my library is going in an entirely different direction.

Comment: You might want to check out monet.js http://cwmyers.github.io/monet.js/ and start heading down the road of the Monad.

That said, that seems like an awful lot of extra, hard-for-others-to-decipher-intent-later code for something you can do expressively like this:

    _.chain(json).get('posts').map('title').value(); 

lodash/underscore would be a lot easier to partially apply if the arguments of functions like map were reversed, but alas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Hugh Jackson's (excellent!) article, the `then` functions would presumably be coming from a Promise library, probably tied to an AJAX call.  So you wouldn't need to do it yourself, if you were starting there.  Mixing it into `_` like that does seem odd.

Lo-Dash and Underscore will allow you to do this with their `curry` functions.  Some newer libraries such as **[Ramda](https://github.com/ramda/ramda)** and **[FKit](https://github.com/nullobject/fkit)** do this automatically.   Their versions of `get` and `map` are already curried, and designed to be used this way. (Disclosure: I am one of the authors of Ramda)

Comment: I am aware that he means async stuff. However, it seems usefull to apply your own function to an object and pipe the result to the next function, also in a synchronous situation.